# How does Schema Registry integrate with Kafka Source Connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have added Topic-Key and Topic-Value schemas for a given topic using REST APIs. In my custom connector, do I need to create a schema again using SchemaBuilder? How do I access the registered schemas inside my connector ?